# 'userRole': userRole, sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to make this select statment from two days, everytime i get error,

```
    course_user="Python"
    userRole="Student"


    my_cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(userTable.user_id), userTable.name FROM userTable, courseTable WHERE :courseTable.course_name, :userTable.role",
    {
        'course_name':  course_user,
        'userRole': userRole
        })

    result = my_cur.fetchall()

    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge use:-

```
my_cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(UserTable.user_id), userTable.name FROM userTable WHERE course_name=%s AND userRole=%s" % (course_user, userRole)
```

Comment: now it is saying now sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: course_name           But in my table I have columne course_name, I copied exactly same name and pasted to check spelling mistak I have two tables

Comment: You have to create column name If you want to search/query. See:-https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: If you are a beginner try with mysql

Comment: I recommend to remake the tables or create a fresh tale

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, this worked for me,        my_cur.execute("SELECT * FROM userTable INNER JOIN courseTable ON userTable.user_id = courseTable.user_id WHERE courseTable.course_name=? and userTable.role=?", (course_user, userRole))